# android imagebutton click event in xml

Tags: android, imagebutton

i define an imagebutton like this:

```
<ImageButton android:src="@raw/blaimage" />
```

now how can i also define which method should be called when the button is clicked.

in the android documentation it says that you can use onClick but it doesnt seem to compile for me.

```
 android:onClick="selfDestruct"
```

and in the activity i have:

```
 public void selfDestruct(View view) {
     // Kabloey
 }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: Please show how you have implemented the selfDestruct method from your activity

Comment: You need to put some code inside the method to implement what you want the click on the button to DO. It's confusing for the dev docs to call it selfDestruct. As it stands it does nothing.

Comment: Ok, this is correct. I have tried with a simple example and it works with the code above. Do you have some error messages? Does your blaimage exist (error in the xml file) ?

Comment: yes the error is in the xml. i think i just found what it was. i am targeting 1.5 and it seems that feature is not yet available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just found out, what the problem was.
i was targeting android 1.5 but this feature is only available since API level 4 which is 1.6

Answer (score 1):

When you get inflated your layout your button is available by id. So you can set any code to be executed when the button is clicked:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 void onClick(...) {
   // your code here
}
};
```

Remember, that you should specify the id of your button like this(here it is `button_id`)

Comment: thanks, but i want to do that in the xml file and not in the code